# Deploying spring boot on Google cloud with SSL certificate

Tags: firebase, ssl, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have deployed my angular on Firebase. I have connected my custom domain as well. Firebase has issued me a certificate for my custom domain. Now I want to deploy spring boot on Google cloud. I am totally fine with compute engine or App engine. But I want to use the SSL certificate provided by Firebase for my front-end angular app in the backend spring boot application. I don't want to bring up a load-balancer.
What are my available options?

Should I go with nginx configurations ?
How will I access the certificate firebase has issues for my frontend app ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud does not provide private keys for Managed SSL Certificates. Without the private key, you cannot deploy the SSL certificate on your own services (Nginx, Apache, Spring Boot, etc).

You must use a Google Cloud service with a managed SSL certificate.

Your other options are:

- Purchase an SSL certificate from a CA
- Configure Let's Encrypt to issue SSL certificates